# Move xcode iphone application

Tags: iphone, xcode, testing

i've just finished my first iphone app. Now i want to give my app to some person that can test it, is possible to give them only the application files without the code, something that they can install into their simulator and run?

Answer (score 2):

Every app in your simulator has a folder on your computer that contains the app. You can find the simulator folder here:

/Users/[USERNAME]/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications

Here you should have a folder for each app you've installed on the simulator. Copy the folder for your application, and place it in the other computer's simulator applications folder.... this should allow that other simulator to run your app.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to google is "Ad Hoc Distribution". LOTS of resources out there to show you how to do that.

The short version is, you'll get your distribution certificate from Apple, register their UUID to an app certificate, make a build with that certificate embedded in it, and send them that file to install via iTunes.

EDIT: Sorry... Then I READ your question. My answer is good if you want to send it to a DEVICE. There's no way to distribute to another user's SIMULATOR without sending them your source.